# mongodb keyfile permission denied

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, permissions, access-control

I configured in `/etc/mongod.conf` to enforce keyfile access control, in `security` option enabled, `keyFile` is `/root/dbtest.key` (the absolute path of keyfile). I already gave the ownership to `mongodb` user by `chown`, and granted `400` permission on that `dbtest.key` file.

But `mongod` keeps failing to start, after checking log, the error is `Error reading file /root/dbtest.key: Permission denied`. After checking the ownership and permissions on `dbtest.key`

[image]

Which means I already granted correctly. So I don't know at which step I did wrong

Comment: Are you using sudo to run `mongod`?

Comment: the permission should be set to `mongod` instead of `mongodb` because that's the user.

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti Sure I did
@vikscool When I tried to grant `mongod` user, the system said that there is no `mongod` user. Besides, when I check `ps aux`, it said that `mongodb` is the user that runs `mongod` service

Comment: Run mongod without sudo, and see if you are able to

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti Still the same error